# Web scraping with R, content

Tags: r, web, html-parsing, screen-scraping, rvest

I am just starting with web scraping in R, I put this code:

```
mps <- read_html("http://tunisie-annonce.com/AnnoncesImmobilier.asp")

mps %>%
    html_nodes("tr") %>%
    html_text()
```

To get the needed content that I put in a text file. My problem is that I want to eliminate these red points, but I can't. Could you please help me?
I think these points are replacing `<b>` and `<br>` in the html code.

[image]

Comment: The landing page contains a table. Your purpose is not clear to me, do you want to extract the content of that table and have in a data.frame in R? or maybe you are interested in other contents of the page?

Comment: @SabDeM yes yes I want to extract the content of the table. I extracted that text and I just need ti eliminate that weird points to put the in a data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever constructed that page very frustratingly assembled the table within a table, but not defined as a `<table>` tag itself, so it's easiest to redefine it so it will parse more easily:

```r
library(rvest)

mps <- read_html("http://tunisie-annonce.com/AnnoncesImmobilier.asp")

df <- mps %>%
    html_nodes("tr.Entete1, tr.Tableau1") %>%    # get correct rows
    paste(collapse = '\n') %>%     # paste nodes back to a single string
    paste('<table>', ., '</table>') %>%     # add enclosing table node
    read_html() %>%    # reread as HTML
    html_node('table') %>% 
    html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%    # parse as table
    { setNames(.[-1,], make.names(.[1,], unique = TRUE)) }    # grab names from first row

head(df)
#>          X          Région NA.           Nature NA..1        Type NA..2
#> 2     Prix            <NA>  NA             <NA>    NA        <NA>    NA
#> 3 Modifiée                  NA             <NA>    NA        <NA>    NA
#> 4                  Kelibia  NA          Terrain    NA  Terrain nu    NA
#> 5          Cite El Ghazala  NA         Location    NA App. 4 pièc    NA
#> 6                 Le Bardo  NA         Location    NA App. 1 pièc    NA
#> 7                 Le Bardo  NA Location vacance    NA App. 3 pièc    NA
#>                   Texte.annonce NA..3   Prix Prix.1        X.1 Modifiée
#> 2                          <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     <NA>
#> 3                          <NA>    NA   <NA>   <NA>       <NA>     <NA>
#> 4      Terrain a 5 km de kelibi    NA 80 000        07/05/2017         
#> 5      S plus 3 haut standing c    NA    790        07/05/2017         
#> 6          Appartements meubles    NA 40 000        07/05/2017         
#> 7 Un bel appartement au bardo m    NA    420        07/05/2017         
#>   Modifiée.1 NA..4 NA..5
#> 2       <NA>    NA    NA
#> 3       <NA>    NA    NA
#> 4       <NA>    NA    NA
#> 5       <NA>    NA    NA
#> 6       <NA>    NA    NA
#> 7       <NA>    NA    NA
```

Note there's a lot of `NA`s and other cruft here yet to be cleaned up, but at least it's usable at this point.

Comment: Thank youuuuu veryyy much! You are saving my life! It's exactly what I need. I wil work now on eliminating that NA thank you very muuuch

Answer (score 0):

You can always use regular expressions to remove undesired chars, e.g.,

```
mps <- gsub("•", " ", mps)
```

Comment: Thak you @mkearney BUt I tried that and it did not work. the points are special, it's not about simple characters...

Comment: thank you @mkearny! but the problem here is that points are not like normal characters. they can't be eliminated with gsub